# The batch file cannot be found while deleting git branch in batch file

Tags: git, batch-file, merge

I am trying to perform some subtree sync in my repo, I wanted to do it using a batch file that creates a temporary git branch, merges the changes, commits and pushes them and then wants to delete the temporary branch. All the operations succeed except for the git delete branch, which gives the message: ***The batch file cannot be found***

Batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
PUSHD "%~dp0"
SET MERGEBRANCH=%USERNAME%/merge/dotbuild
git checkout -b %MERGEBRANCH%
git remote add -f dotbuild <repo_path>
git pull dotbuild master
git merge --squash -s subtree -X theirs --allow-unrelated-histories --no-commit dotbuild/master
git add .
git commit -m "Pull updates from DotBuild"
git push --set-upstream origin %MERGEBRANCH%
git remote rm dotbuild
git checkout master
git branch -D %MERGEBRANCH%
POPD
ENDLOCAL
```

Answer (score 0):

That kind of error is seen mostly on Windows 7, not Windows 10, [as in here](https://github.com/expo/create-react-native-app/issues/367#issuecomment-393919935) (nor node, but a similar idea must apply to your sequence of Git commands):

> I just tried running eject on Windows 7 64-bit. Since the `cmd.exe` (The command line of windows 7) does not read batchfiles in total into memory to execute them and is reading and executing the commands one by one after each other the Error is raised.
>
> Somewhere in the later steps when node_modules is being deleted it also deletes the dependency which is implementing the batch file midway in the eject process. But since the Windows 7 console needs to read it again to execute the next command or to know that the there are no other commands left to execute it is throwing the error message
>
> As far as I heared the setup should be working in Windows 10 since the comandline there was completly reworked.

Comment: Weirdly, I am facing this on Windows 10. Could you think of any solution?

Comment: @RichaDua First simplify the script to see if the issue persists: for instance, keep only the creation  / dleetion of the branch. SEcond, set echo to on, in order to confirm the exact moment the error occurs. What version of Git for Windows are you using?

Comment: I tried to simplify it and find which line is causing the error mentioned. It seems like it fails at branch delete when preceded by a commit before, Could you possibly think of why?

Comment: @RichaDua What is the value of `MERGEBRANCH` when it fails?

Comment: It is the same <username>/merge/dotbuild

Comment: @RichaDua Can you try `git branch -D -- %MERGEBRANCH%` (double `-` between the command and the branch name)? For testing, can you also try not including the username in the branch name?

Comment: Adding -- to the branch delete command didn't work unfortunately.